# Using Protractor with proxypass-based AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, protractor, proxypass

I'm using [Protractor](http://protractortest.org) to implement end-to-end tests on my AngularJS app using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com), and my app does use proxy pass to handle API calls. As a result, when running tests, API calls fail because `http://localhost:9000/api` is not handled.

I tried the [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) plugin to handle `/api` proxy pass but it simply redirects (HTTP code 301) `localhost:9000/api` to `myserver.com/api`, and doesn't mimic the behaviour of a proxy pass (and the app doesn't work either).

Here's the Gruntfile configuration:

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        base: ['<%= globals.appFolder %>/'],
        logger: 'dev',
    }
},

protractor: {
    options: {
        configFile: 'tests/e2e/protractor.config.js',
        keepAlive: true,
        noColor: false,
        args: {}
    },
    e2e: {
        options: {
           args: {}
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the Protractor configuration file:

```
exports.config =  {
    specs: ['./suites/*.js'],
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
    maxSessions: 1,
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
};
```

How would you handle this case to let tests **run on both a desktop machine, and a remote machine** (such as Jenkins)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/144) related on *grunt-connect-proxy*, this is a bug occurring when dealing with HTTPS endpoints. Use the `master/` version instead.

Package.json:

```
"grunt-connect-proxy": "https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy#master",
```

Gruntfile:

```
proxies: [{
    context: '/api',
    host: 'myserver.com',
    port: 443,
    https: true
}]
```